# The intervals on which the function W is increasing and on which it is decreasing

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is the function $W$:

[image]

(1) Determine the intervals on which the function $W$ is increasing and on which it is decreasing.

- a. The function W is increasing on [100, 200] and [300, 365] and decreasing on [0, 100] and [200, 300].
- b. The function W is increasing on [150, 300] and decreasing on [0, 150] and [300, 365].
- c. The function W is increasing on [50, 80] and [25, 75] and decreasing on [80, 25].
- d. The function W is increasing on [0, 150] and [300, 365] and decreasing on [150, 300].

(2) At what value of x does W achieve a local maximum?

(3) At what value of x does W achieve a local minimum?

To be honest I have no real idea on how these are solved

Please explain, Thank You

Answer (score 1):

It is increasing wherever it goes upwards.  You are expected to look at the $x$ axis for the points where it starts and stops increasing.  Starts and stops can be at the ends of the interval, or look like mountain tops and valleys.  A local maximum is a hilltop (as nearby points are lower) and a local minimum is a valley (as nearby points are higher).

Comment: I think I understand the last two. Being x = 150days for the local maximum. And x = 300 days for the local minimum. However, I am still confused on what question one is asking. It looks like it is increasing at 0 then stops at 150 as it begins its decent. And descends from 150 and levels out at 300 as it starts its increase. I don't understand which answer this would satisfy this.

Comment: That is exactly answer d.  It increases from the start at 0 to 150 and again from 300 to the end at 365, and decreases from 150 to 300.  The value at 300 could be above the value at 0-that doesn't matter at all.